# ACE editor font style over ride by my existing font styles

Tags: css, fonts, ace-editor

I'm using ACE editor. .ace_editor font style is

```
.ace_editor {
    direction: ltr; 
    font: 12px 'Monaco','Menlo','Ubuntu Mono','Consolas','source-code-pro',monospace;
}
```

That font is overridden by my existing font-family:

```
*, *:before, *:after {
     font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif !important;
}
```

So the cursor works like `This is text           |` . How can i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

```
 body {
    font-family: "Open Sans",sans-serif;
 }
```

this just fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

do not use `*, *:before, *:after {font-family:...}`. you can use `body {font-family:...}` instead.
However if you can't change that rule with `*` selector, add

```
.ace_editor{
   font-family:'Monaco','Menlo','Ubuntu Mono','Consolas',
       'source-code-pro',monospace !important;
}
```

Comment: @ a user Thanks for the answer. I tried this already but no luck! Because I Call this (*, *:before, *:after {font-family:...}) from  external CSS. That css file using whole application.

Comment: Try increasing specificity of `.ace_editor` selector, e.g add id to the element and use #id.ace_editor